# NSManagedObject subclass' category equivalent in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I just started Swift and usually in Objective-C I create a category for each one of my NSManagedObject subclasses so the category isn't erased each time I have to generate my subclass. Moreover, it can simplify the creation of CoreData objects, especially when populated by data coming from a JSON.

**Example :**

My NSManagedObject subclass :

```
@class Book;

@interface Book : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * author;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * plot;
@end
```

Its "helper" category implementation :

```
+ (Book*)bookFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context {
    Book *book = nil;

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Book"];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@", dictionary[@"name"]];
    request.fetchLimit = 1;

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *result = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    if (!result || error) {
        NSLog(@"Error getting Book : %@", error.localizedDescription);
    } else if ([result count] == 0) {
        book = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Book" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    } else {
        book = [result lastObject];
    }

    self.name = dictionary[@"name"];
    self.author = dictionary[@"author"];
    self.plot = dictionary[@"plot"];

    return book;
}
```

I'm trying to reproduce this concept in Swift but I don't have any idea how.
It seems that extensions replace categories in Swift but if I implement an extension into a NSManagedObject subclass in Swift, it will be erased each time I have to generate my NSManagedObject subclass (because it's in the same file...). And that's why I used to create categories in Obj-C.

Can someone tell me what are the good practices about this in Swift ?

I would greatly appreciate any help !

Comment: Categories are the correct way to do this in ObjC (obvious, once you've been bitten, but why doesn't the boilerplate Xcode produces not include comments to this effect?) In Swift, I use extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Swift extension is the right way to define additional methods for  `NSManagedObject` subclasses.
You can put the extension into a separate file
(e.g. "BookExtensions.swift") so that they are not overwritten when
"Book.swift" is recreated in Xcode.

Comment: Right now I would not recommend letting Xcode create the subclasses.  Run into a few issues with nillable properties.

Comment: By not letting Xcode create the subclasses, do you mean not using a data model file at all ? Or do I have to maintain NSManagedObject subclass programmatically and at the same time an equivalent data model file ?

Comment: Another question (I couldn't edit anymore...). Is mogenerator a good alternative to resolve this kind of problem (still in Swift) ?

Answer (score 0):

There are issues in generating the subclasses for `NSManagedObjects` in Swift. Typically, you have to go through them again manually to e.g. change types into optionals, include markers like `@objc(Class)` etc.

Therefore, I have changed my workflow: I am now including the custom methods in the generated file *without* using an `extension` (which is the Swift equivalent of a category). When updating my managed object model, I just change the the file marginally by adding, renaming, changing etc. the attributes and relationships.